# Query plugin NiceScroll appears below the container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nicescroll

I have asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132697/nicescroll-generates-the-scrollbars-down-from-the-top-of-the-destination-div) but no one replied.. The plugin [nicescroll](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/) positions its scroll bars displaced by 30px from the top of the container. I tried to peek into many examples but no clue. Help will be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Can you put it in jfiddle?

Comment: creating fiddle will be difficult here as the code is generated by aspx so I don't understand on which basis to create fiddle

Comment: View source in browser will give you the generated HTML.

Comment: Well, i need to see it visually to determine, if its css or javascript problem.

Comment: Sorry the page is very big and lots of other things. Creating Jsfiddle seems very difficult.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show us code. Besides this is a Q&A site where, as a community, it would be nice to see code so that if somebody else comes across this problem they can potentially use the fix that someone may have for you...